# Thread doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm using *Xamarin Studio* to develop Android apps.

The app should generate 50 entries in `lvRes` (ListView).
My following code example works perfectly fine except the first try.

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bnCalc)
.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => new Java.Lang.Thread(() => {
    ListView lvRes = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvRes);
    ArrayAdapter res = new ArrayAdapter(lvRes.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
    lvRes.Adapter = res;

    ulong a = 1;
    ulong b = 1;
    ulong tmp;
    int step = 0;

    while (++step <= 50 && (tmp = a + b) < ulong.MaxValue) {
        res.Add(tmp.ToString());
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
}).Start();
```

After the first click on `bnCalc` (Button), `lvRes` gets just one entry.
Every following click on `bnCalc` fills `lvRes` with 50 entries.

Comment: did you tried to put a break point in the while because I think it is a UI problem and not thread problem

Comment: Why is there a thread?

Comment: I didn't try to set breakpoints yet; I wanted the app to generate the numbers in background to prevent a freezed UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@User3805967 said, it could be a UI problem. So I set a breakpoint to check, if the while loop works. The loop works like it should. So I tried to pass the ArrayAdapter to the ListView after generating all numbers. And it works perfectly. Now my code looks like the following example:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bnCalc)
.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => new Java.Lang.Thread(() => {
    ulong a = 1;
    ulong b = 1;
    ulong tmp;
    int step = 0;

    ListView lvRes = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvRes);
    ArrayAdapter res = new ArrayAdapter(lvRes.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);

    try {
        while (++step <= count && (tmp = a + b) < max) {
            res.Add(tmp.ToString());
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
    } catch(System.Exception) {}

    // After generating numbers, I assign the ArrayAdapter to the ListView
    RunOnUiThread(() => lvRes.Adapter = res);
}).Start();
```